# Defining the BinarySearch for a user defined class in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have defined a class for storing the GPS data in Java as follows :

```
class data implements Comparable
{
        float lati;
        float longi;
        int time; // Time in seconds 
        public int compareTo(Object obj)
        {
                data t = (data)obj;
                if(this.time == t.time)
                        return 0;
                if(this.time< t.time)
                        return -1;
                else
                        return 1;
        }
}
```

I have stored all the data in an ArrayList which I have sorted using the Collections.sort(d1) .(here d1 ArrayList of data type objects). But I am facing the problem is how can I use the Collections.binarySearch on this ArrayList to find the index of a specific element. When I try using it, I get the error message that binarySearch can'b be used with this data type. Can someone please help.

Comment: note: to use a indexedBinarySearch your list must have a size less than 5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparable needs a parameter. Try with the following class:

```
class Data implements Comparable<Data> {

    float lati;
    float longi;
    Integer time;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data o) {
        // Integer already implements Comparable
        return time.compareTo(o.time);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example on how to do it.

```
import java.util.*;

class Data implements Comparable<Data>
{
    float lati;
    float longi;
    int time; // Time in seconds 

    public Data(int time) { this.time = time; }

    public int compareTo(Data obj)
    {
            if(this.time == obj.time)
                    return 0;
            if(this.time< obj.time)
                    return -1;
            else
                    return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Data> dataArray = new ArrayList<>();
        dataArray.add(new Data(3));
        dataArray.add(new Data(1));
        dataArray.add(new Data(2));

        Collections.sort(dataArray);
        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(dataArray,new Data(1)));
        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(dataArray,new Data(3)));
        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(dataArray,new Data(2)));
    }
}
```